# Enable button functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this form that the functionality is when all the required fields are completed to enable the submit button.
It was working until i added more interaction for a map gallery.
What could be wrong?
Im open to any suggestion or advice.
Im pretty new

Html

```
<h1>Contact me</h1>
    <form action="" id="ContactForm" onsubmit="sConsole(event)">
        <fieldset>
        <p><label for="fullname">First Name:</label></p>
            <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required />    
        <p><label for="lastname">Last Name:</label></p>
            <input type="text"  id="lastname" name="lastname" > 
        <p><label for="email">Email:</label></p>
            <input type="email"id="email" email="email"  required /> 
        <p>Comment</p>
        <label> 
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="30"  placeholder="Insert your comments here..."  required ></textarea>
        </label>
        <p>Date of birth</p>
        <label for="mydate">Pick a date:</label>
        <input type="date"  id="date"  required />
        
        <input type="submit" id="SubmitButton" disabled = "disabled"  value="submit" onClick="sConsole()">
        
        </fieldset>
```

Javascript

```
ContactForm.addEventListener("input" , () => {
    if (fullname.value.length > 0 && 
        lastname.value.length > 0 &&
        email.value.length > 0 &&
        comments.value.length > 0 &&
        date.value.length > 0) {
          SubmitButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        } else {
          SubmitButton.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
        }
      });
```

The new things that i added

```
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev");
  const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next");
  const mapGallery = document.querySelectorAll(".maps-gallery");
  
  let currentlySelected = 0;
   
  prevBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    mapGallery[currentlySelected].classList.remove("active");
    currentlySelected--; 
    mapGallery[currentlySelected].classList.add("active");
    nextBtn.disabled = false
    if (currentlySelected === 0){
      prevBtn.disabled = true;

    }

  });

  nextBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    mapGallery[currentlySelected].classList.remove("active");
    currentlySelected++;
    mapGallery[currentlySelected].classList.add("active");
    prevBtn.disabled = false
    if (mapGallery.length === currentlySelected +1 ){
      nextBtn.disabled = true;
  
  }
  });
```

Comment: Did you check the browser's dev tools / console for error messages? Press F12

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactForm is not defined.

Comment: it worked until i added the last code of the maps gallery

Comment: That error is unrelated to the code you added; did you also move the script to your document's <head> maybe? If so, move it back down, right before `</body>` (the ending tag, not the opening one!) The reason for the error is simple: at the time when `ContactForm.addEventListener("input" , () => {` runs, `<form action="" id="ContactForm" onsubmit="sConsole(event)">` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: no its on the <body>.

Comment: Is the script above the form? Or below it?

Comment: the script is another file named portafolio.js. its above the form

Comment: It needs to be below. Because when it runs, the form doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
document.getElementById("ContactForm").addEventListener
```

in the code. In this case, JavaScript needs to know the ID of the element to access.